# Import email addresses to mail group using Plesk

Tags: web-hosting, email, plesk

My web hosting service uses Parallels Plesk Panel 9.5 as their Control Panel. I just created a mail group (like a distribution list, one email address to email multiple people).

I can only add ONE email address at a time through the Control Panel, and I have hundreds of emails to upload. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you better get on with it ;)

Comment: Serious note this should be something your web host should be able to answer, I'm sure there is a bulk way of creating the alias but limited on your user group within Plesk. Submit a ticket.

Comment: Yes, bybe; work harder, not smarter. I know you are being snarky, but isn't it true that the best programmers are lazy ones? "I don't want to do this more than three times, maybe I can write a script to do it for me!"

Comment: Sadly, my help desk is, um, not always the sharpest tool in the drawer. I asked, they had no idea. They seemed confused by the concept, actually.

Comment: Are you migrating from one system to plesk? if so what did the old system use.

Comment: This is a new web site. I have a few hundred emails in excel. I am pretty good at importing and exporting, but there doesn't seem to be a mechanism in plesk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after investigating this is something you can't do in Plesk control panel but it can be done via SSH.

You can easily create email address using SSH using the Command Line Utilities for Plesk these are normally located in /PRODUCT_ROOT_D/bin and /PRODUCT_ROOT_D/bin/mail.sh

The mail command line tool supports:

- enabling or disabling mail service on a domain
- creating and deleting mail accounts
- editing mail account settings
- managing mail groups associated with mail accounts
- managing mail user control panel access
- managing mail user control panel interface parameters

So sadly this looks like your going to have to bash on at your provider and without offence if they can't do simple tasks as this then its time to reconsider them as a long term provider for managing your needs for your business because if this is headache what else is going to be?... You should be able to pass them that spreadsheet of the accounts you want created and they should be able to create a script which prefixes the commandlines to each email and simply batch creates them. It's easier than it sounds.

Comment: Is this something I can do, or do they have to do it on the server?

Comment: They would need to give you SSH access and permissions that allow you to run the command-line. So the likelihood is they will need to do unless they are willing to pass the permissions which any good web host provider will not because you could do damage to other users.

Comment: I'd personally pass the excel sheet to them and tell them to get on with it.

Comment: Well, my beloved Hosting Service wants to charge me $15 for the privilege. I just sat down with NotePad and a browser and cut and pasted all 172 email addresses. It was less hassle. I told them I would keep this incident in mind come renewal time.

Answer (score 1):

Plesk Panel 9.5 is extremely old software. Its support will soon be [terminated by vendor](http://www.parallels.com/plesk/lifecycle/). If your provider can upgrade you to more up2date version like 10.x or 11.0, you can solve the task very easy - there is a textarea to copy/paste all your recipients (just one recipient per line)

Comment: I doubt my web hosting company will switch before my current contract with them runs out, guess I will be shopping around for a new host.